# How to use union after foreach the 2nd table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to use `union()` after I foreach the 2nd table. But it give me an error. Please see my code below.

**Code**

```
$customers = Customer::select(['email', 'name']);
$clients = Client::select('email', 'name'])->get();

$total_clients = [];

foreach($clients as $client) {

  if($status == 7 && $client->email != "j@domain.com" && $client->name == "A") {
    continue;
  }

  $total_clients[] = $client;

}

$all_clients = collect($total_clients);


$customers->unionAll($clients)->get();
```

**Error**

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
> Method getBindings does not exist.

**Laravel Version**

5.2

Comment: You can't use unions like that.

Comment: `$clients` also needs to be a builder, `unionAll` takes a builder ... also this loop isn't doing anything in relation to this union so not sure what it is for ... and Laravel 5.2, really?

Comment: @lagbox So it means, I cannot use `unionAll` method for models? The loop is to skip the row that matches the condition inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from the fact that `$customers` is still a Builder object.

I assume you are wanting to use the `union` method on the Collection, in which case you need to `get()` the `$customers`;

```
$customers = Customer::select(['email', 'name'])->get();
```

Comment: I don't want it to be a collection as much as possible. I actually want to use `unionAll()` instead of a `union`, but unfortunately my models turns as a collection. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

untested but can you try this:

```
$customers = Customer::select(['email', 'name']);
$clients = Client::
  select('email', 'name'])
->where('email', '!=', 'j@domain.com')
->where('name', 'A');
    
if($status == 7)
  $customers = $customers->union($clients);
    
$customers = $customers->get();
```

Comment: I'm using `continue` inside the foreach so basically I wanted to skip the row where the condition is met.